# Cannot find module '@cypress/code-coverage/task'

Tags: cypress, browserstack

I'm using cypress to automate browserstack, I try to automate from local first, but when I `npx browserstack-cypress run –sync`, there's error:

```
error: Cypress could not run any of the specs in the build since an exception occurred. The stacktrace of the error is given below:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Your pluginsFile threw an error from: .\tests\e2e\plugins\index.js


Error: Cannot find module '@cypress/code-coverage/task'
Require stack:
- .\tests\e2e\plugins\index.js
- \cypress_package\9.6.1\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\child\run_plugins.js
- \cypress_package\9.6.1\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\child\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
    at module.exports (.\tests\e2e\plugins\index.js:17:14)
    at \cypress_package\9.6.1\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\child\run_plugins.js:94:12
    at tryCatcher (\cypress_package\9.6.1\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Function.Promise.attempt.Promise.try (\cypress_package\9.6.1\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\method.js:39:29)
    at load (\cypress_package\9.6.1\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\child\run_plugins.js:91:7)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (\cypress_package\9.6.1\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\child\run_plugins.js:209:5)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at process.<anonymous> (\cypress_package\9.6.1\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\util.js:19:22)
    at process.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:912:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21)

cypress run process exited with code 1
cypress run failed, exiting with code: 1
```

And here is my code:

**./browserstack.json**

```
{
    "auth": {
        "username": "XXXX",
        "access_key": "XXXX"
    },
    "browsers": [
        {
            "browser": "chrome",
            "os": "Windows 10",
            "versions": [
                "latest",
                "latest-1"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "run_settings": {
        "cypress_config_file": "./cypress.json",
        "project_name": "project-name",
        "build_name": "build-name",
        "exclude": [],
        "parallels": 5,
        "npm_dependencies": {},
        "package_config_options": {},
        "headless": true,
        "spec_timeout": 10
    },
    "connection_settings": {
        "local": false,
        "local_identifier": null,
        "local_mode": null,
        "local_config_file": null
    },
    "disable_usage_reporting": false
}
```

**./cypress.json**

```
{
  "pluginsFile": "tests/e2e/plugins/index.js",
  "viewportWidth": 1280,
  "viewportHeight": 800
}
```

**./tests/e2e/plugins/index.js**

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on("task", require("@cypress/code-coverage/task"));
  on("file:preprocessor", require("@cypress/code-coverage/use-browserify-istanbul"));

  return Object.assign({}, config, {
    fixturesFolder: "tests/e2e/fixtures",
    integrationFolder: "tests/e2e/specs",
    screenshotsFolder: "tests/e2e/screenshots",
    videosFolder: "tests/e2e/videos",
    supportFile: "tests/e2e/support/index.js"
  });
};
```

**./tests/e2e/support/index.js**

```
import '@cypress/code-coverage/support';  // I DO import code-coverage here
import "./commands";

require('cypress-xpath');
```

If I delete `pluginsFile` in `cypress.json`, and add test in `./cypress/integration`, then everything will be just find.
I don't know that I did anything wrong, please help, thanks.

Comment: Have you installed the `cypress/code-coverage` plugin? Silly question, just checking. Also, make sure you get v2 - v3 is for Cypress 10.